# How to retrieve PID from windows event log?

Tags: python, wmi, pid, wmi-query, event-viewer

[image]I have a python code that uses WMI module of python to get windows event viewer logs. But I am unable to retrieve the PID of the process that generated the log.
My code :

```
wmi_obj = wmi.WMI('.') #Initialize WMI object and query.
wmi_query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile='System' AND EventType=1"
query_result = wmi_obj.query(wmi_query) # Query WMI object
```

query_result is a list of wmi objects. Each object in this list is a windows system log and I want PID of the process that generated this log.
I have gone through several msdn docs but couldn't find anything useful there.

I want to retrieve the information marked in the above image.

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 API call to get event log items is [ReadEventLog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363674(v=vs.85).aspx) and this returns [EVENTLOGRECORD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363646(v=vs.85).aspx) structures. These do not have a field for a process identifier so unless your events have included this in the data of the event message it looks like this will not be available.

Comment: The first argument to ReadEventLog is a handle to the event log to be read. The OpenEventLog function returns this handle. You can use the handle to get the pid.

Comment: Both the suggestion didn't solve what I was looking for. If you check the event logs in windows, under the details section for a particular log you will find the process ID that triggered that log, but I am unable to find a way to retrieve it.